# One of $2^1-1,2^2-1,...,2^n-1$ is divisible by $n$ for odd $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $n$ be an odd integer greater than 1. Show that one of the numbers $2^1-1,2^2-1,...,2^n-1$ is divisible by $n$.

I know that pigeonhole principle would be helpful, but how should I apply it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that there are $n$ such number with the possible number of remainders is $n-1$ from $1,2,\cdots,n-2,n-1$ because  if $0$  is a remainder for some $r,$ then $n|(2^r-1)$ and we are done.

Otherwise using [Pigeonhole Principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PigeonholePrinciple.html), at least for two distinct values $r$ we shall have same remainder

Let $2^t-1\equiv2^s-1\pmod n$ where $t>s$

$\implies n|\{(2^t-1)-(2^s-1)\}\implies n| 2^s(2^{t-s}-1)\implies n|(2^{t-s}-1)$ as $(2,n)=1$

Clearly, $0<t-s<n$ as $n\ge t>s\ge1$

Comment: Why $n|\{(2^t-1)-(2^s-1)\}\implies n| 2^{t-s}(2^s-1)$ ?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ, sorry for the mistake, rectified

Comment: Isn't it strange? Our result contradict with our assumption "the possible number of remainders is n−1".

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ, to me it's a proof by contradiction

Comment: Interestingly, $r-s= \phi(n)$.:)

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee, Thanks~

Comment: @Inceptio, $r-s$ is actually $\lambda(n)$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael Function(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html)

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ, welcome, hope I could make the idea clear

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Yes, I have heard of it. I just looked on few numbers and found it to be $\phi(n)$.

Comment: @Inceptio, have you tried with composite $n$ with at least two odd prime factors like $15,21,30$  etc. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;2^k-1=2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+\ldots+2+1\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\text{Every natural number $\,n\,$ can be uniquely written in base two }$$

$$\text{with maximal power of two less than $\,n\,$ }$$

Comment: I deleted my post almost immediately after I posted since I thought I misunderstood the question, yet thanks to Lab's answer I see I in fact misunderstood that I misunderstood..

Comment: This is supposed to be great hint, because it involves no pigeon-hole principle. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We know that $\gcd(2,n)=1$

$2^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod n$

And $1<\phi(n)<n$ and we already have $2^1-1 \equiv 1 \pmod n$

You can use pigeon-hole principle after this.

**Another Approach:**

Actually, the $\phi(n)$ or $\lambda(n)$ occurs just between $1$ and $n$, therefore,

$2^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n  \implies 2^{\lambda(n)} -1 \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

This involves *no* Pigeons or Pigeon-holes.:)

Here $\lambda(n)$ is smallest number which occurs before $\phi(n)$ such that $a^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$. Also known as [Carmichael Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Comment: Will it be $\not\equiv?$

Comment: No. There was a typo in $2^1$ part. Edited it.:)